# Value Error when using GridSearchCV with sklearn.svm for c and gamma

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, cross-validation, grid-search

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel="rbf" , C = 1 , gamma = 1, probability = True)
from sklearn.grid_search import GridSearchCV

gamma_range = [1e-2,1e-1,1e0,1e1,1e2]
c_range = [1e-2,1e-1,1e0,1e1,1e2]
param_grid = dict(gamma = gamma_range, c = c_range)
print param_grid
```

gives:

```
{'c': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0], 'gamma': [0.01, 0.1, 1.0, 10.0, 100.0]}
```

as expected, but when I run  the next bit of code:

```
grid = GridSearchCV(clf, param_grid, cv= 10, scoring="accuracy")
grid.fit(X_norm, y)
```

I get this: ValueError: Invalid parameter c for estimator SVC

I'm pretty sure these are valid values for c, as I've manually run them through myself, im just looking to fine tune everything.

Comment: Just a thought, but your dict key is `c` (lowercase) and the parameter in the first line is `C` (uppercase).

Comment: You're right! How silly of me